AWS Lambda and X-Ray -> segment not existing
I am using python and aws-xray-sdk. I have enabled x-ray for lambda function (tracing: Tracing.ACTIVE) and for api gateway (tracingEnabled: true)
I can see a trace and client -> api gateway stage -> lambda context -> lambda function at x-ray dashboard, but I cannot see anythin else.
What I get at logs is:

START RequestId: REDACTED Version: $LATEST
cannot find the current segment/subsegment, please make sure you have a segment open
cannot find the current segment/subsegment, please make sure you have a segment open
REPORT RequestId: REDACTED Duration: _ ms Billed Duration: _ ms Memory Size: _ MB Max Memory Used: _ MB
XRAY TraceId: REDACTED SegmentId: REDACTED Sampled: true
END RequestId: REDACTED

My python config at start is:
plugins = ('ElasticBeanstalkPlugin', 'EC2Plugin')
xray_recorder.configure(service='**REDACTED**')
xray_recorder.configure(sampling=False)
xray_recorder.configure(plugins=plugins)
xray_recorder.configure(context=AsyncContext())
xray_recorder.configure(context_missing='LOG_ERROR')

patch_all()

If I go and create my own segment, which is detached from request it works
xray_recorder.begin_segment()

But it is not what I am looking for
What am I doing wrong, that I cannot see the traces?
